# SelectBoxIt & ReactJS support needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, drop-down-menu, selectboxit

[SelectBoxIt](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/) allows you to replace ugly and hard-to-use HTML select boxes with gorgeous and feature rich drop downs.

I implemented the SelectBoxIt and the `<select>` inside my `render(return())` method didn't recognize it.
I searched the web and found almost only one [source on Github](https://github.com/gfranko/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/issues/286) that I didn't understand its recommendation, you can help me on this point.

In brief, I concluded that SelectBoxIt naturally doesn't support ReactJS.

Hence we   need a solution or trick for that.

Below is sample code from their website and used it completely in my project:

```
        <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset=utf-8>
      <title>SelectBoxIt demo</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/css/jquery.selectBoxIt.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

      <select name="test">
        <option value="SelectBoxIt is:">SelectBoxIt is:</option>
        <option value="a jQuery Plugin">a jQuery Plugin</option>
        <option value="a Select Box Replacement">a Select Box Replacement</option>
        <option value="a Stateful UI Widget">a Stateful UI Widget</option>
      </select>

      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/js/jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(function() {

          var selectBox = $("select").selectBoxIt();

        });
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The following `select` was not affected:

```
<select 
                id="sel1" 
                // ref={s => { this.selectBox = s; }}
                onChange={ event => this.onSelectChange(event.target.value) }
                >
                {options}
            </select>
```

The `<select name="test">`  has worked when put it inside `render(return())` but the `<select id="sel1" >` inside `render(return())` has not been changed to be a SelectBoxIt shape. Note that I commented the `ref={s => { this.selectBox = s; }}` just to prevent the error to display.

Comment: Clearly react can render anything that's valid javascript or html so unless you're expecting us to use our psychic powers to know what code you've written you're out of luck.

Comment: I updated the post with extra code again.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a jquery plugin, you need to make sure to have it installed:

```
npm install -S jquery
```

Then you need to import this in your script :

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Now in your react component, apply the jquery initialization in componentDidMount. The only catch is that you need to use `ref` to find the node.

```
render() {
  return <select ref={s => { this.selectBox = s; }} />
}

componentDidMount() {
  $(this.selectBox).selectBoxIt();
}
```

Some reference [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html#integrating-with-jquery-chosen-plugin).

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply. It gave me error. TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_jquery__(...).selectBoxIt is not a function ......  It meant this:  $(this.selectBox).selectBoxIt();

Comment: You need to include or import js for selectboxit, can you checkout the docs for selctboxit. Maybe you should add its js file in your index.html.

Answer (score 0):

I found that `reactJS` didn't "catch" `onChange` of the `select` that is replaced with `SelectBoxIt` but it "catch" `onClick`. So for one project that use `SelectBoxIt` + `ReactJS` I've made `onClick` trigger from `jQuery` when `select` value is changed combined with react `onChange` event.

In script tag /index.html/:

```
$("select").on('change',function(){
      $("select").trigger('click');
});
```

In `reactJS` /SelectBox.js/:

`onClickHandled` that check if value is changed.

Example here: https://github.com/gshishkov/selectBoxIt-reactjs

I know it is not very elegant solution, but it was fastest and working one.